# How to make shortcuts depend on layout in PHPStorm?

Tags: settings, keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm

There is the known problem in using shortcuts like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> or any other shortcut with `[]{}`-character in German layout. Normally it's fine to change the most usable shortcut i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> for `Comment with Line Comment`-Shortcut.

The problem now is, that if I'm using both layouts - I want this shortcut to be always on the same place.

US layout:

[image: us/international]

German layout:

[image]

Now if I'm using US layout I have  to use following keys:

[image]

So the question is - is there any way to make shortcuts (keymap) depend on the chosen layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I'm not getting any answer here - I've found small workaround. That's actually not directly an answer to the question, but it solves the problem for users with German layout.

Since I don't use `Ctrl` + `-` in English layout (collapse code block), I've defined both `Ctrl` + `-` and `Ctrl` + `/` for commenting line with line comment. Now I can comment line with pressing red buttons from picture above in both English and German layouts.